# method in class can not be applied to given type

Tags: java, methods, constructor, double

I made a class called that creates a constructer and a method.

```
public class Car
{
private double speed;
private String make;
private int year;

public Car(int year, String make, double speed) {
this.year = year;
this.make = make;
this.speed = speed;
} 

public String getMake(){
  return make;
}
public double getSpeed(){
  return speed;
}
public int getYear(){
     return year;
}


  public void accelerate (double speed)
{
        speed = speed + 1.00;
}


}
```

the only problem i am having here is that when I go to my driver class to try and run it, this is the error I'm receiving

```
public class CarTester
{
public static void main (String[] args){

Car p1 = new Car(2010, "toyota", 4.50);
Car.accelerate();
Car.accelerate();

}
}
```

"error: method accelerate in class Car cannot be applied to given types"

why is that so? because it says "required: double" but the "speed" variable is a double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method

```
public void accelerate(double speed){
speed=speed+1.0;
}
```

Should not be expecting to be passed a "speed"  parameter. It should look simply just like that:

```
public void accelerate(){
speed=speed+1.0;
}
```

Also you should call this method on the Object (p1 in this case).

```
p1.accelerate();
```

Not

```
Car.accelerate();
```

Hope it will help you to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The method shouldn't require parameters

```
public void accelerate () {
    speed = speed + 1.00;
}
```

and must be called from the instance `p1`

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Car p1 = new Car(2010, "toyota", 4.50);
    p1.accelerate();    
    p1.accelerate();
    System.out.println(p1.getSpeed());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`accelerate` is not a static method, so `Car.accelerate ()` can not be called

You have to call it on the Object the you have created i.e. `p1`.

Also - this method expects to be passed the `speed` parameter, but this looks wrong.

I would rewrite it as

```
public void accelerate ()
{
    speed = speed + 1.00;
}
```

as speed is already a field

Alternatively you could leave it as

```
public void accelerate (double speedUpBy)
{
    speed = speed + speedUpBy;
}
```

so that you can specifiy by how much you want to accelerate by

Answer (score 0):

You create a Car object :

```
Car p1 = new Car(2010, "toyota", 4.50);
```

1) But you call accelerate in a static way while   `accelerate (double speed)` is an instance method :

```
Car.accelerate();
Car.accelerate();
```

2) `accelerate()` specifies a parameter but you don't provide it in the method.

You should rather write :

```
car.accelerate(5);
car.accelerate(5);
```

3) This :

```
  public void accelerate (double speed){
        speed = speed + 1.00;
  }
```

will not work as the local variable has the same name as the field name.
A local variable with the same name than a field name shadows the field variable.
To avoid it you should rename the parameter name or better prefixing the field name with `this` when you use it in the method  :

```
  public void accelerate (double speed){
        this.speed = this.speed + speed;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

{ Car c = new Car(2010, "toyota", 4.50); c.accelerate(); System.out.println(c.getSpeed()); }

The code should be like this, called through any object c instead of class Car.